# Opc Da Username and Password

Tags: java, connection, credentials, opc, opc-da

this is my first post, so I apologize if I make some mistakes.
I'm using Utgard opc Da Java library to connect to an opc da server.
What I've noticed is that in order to connect to the server, username and password are required.
Instead, using c#, only url is necessary.
Since at work we use only Java, is there any possibility to avoid inserting username and password? That's because the application will be installed into multiples pc in which we won't know any user credentials.
Sorry for my bad English, Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks In advance to everyone

So, I thought that it was something that could be solved in a short time. However, here what I'm trying to do:

```
private final static String host = "localhost";
private final static String domain = "localhost";
private final static String user = "ramserver1";
private final static String password = "ramserver1";
private final static String clsid = "FAFA7034-4C37-401E-BA8E-7162DB0AC278";
private final static String progId = "ThermoElectron.RESULTOPCServerDA.2";
private ConnectionInformation connectionInformation;
private Server server;
public String readValue;
public Group group;

public OpcConnection() throws JIException, UnknownHostException, 
NotConnectedException, DuplicateGroupException {
    this.connectionInformation = new ConnectionInformation();
    this.connectionInformation.setClsid(clsid);
    this.connectionInformation.setDomain(domain);
    this.connectionInformation.setHost(host);
    this.connectionInformation.setUser(user);
    this.connectionInformation.setPassword(password);
    server = new Server(this.connectionInformation, 
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor());
}
```

Basically, I've created a class OpcConnection: in the constructor, I initialize the parameters needed for the connection. I would like to delete lines in which I set user and password.
Regarding security, I've set Authentication level to none, like this:
[Authentication level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofJGM.png)

What I'm missing?

Comment: You want your code to bypass password and username?

Comment: Yes, basically the only things that i have to use are:  clsid, host and domain

Comment: It's a question of preparing the server. It should allow unprotected connections

Comment: I've done this by going into services and setting the proper permissions. It should be enough but it still doesn't work. Am i missing something? In this case, can you give me please some detailed information?

Comment: I don't think question can be resolved without providing more details. Also, I know nothing about Opc da server so my help does not go further, than finding out, that details are needed

Comment: Ok i Will provide details as soon as i can.

Comment: Anyone that can please give an hand on this?

Answer (score 1):

Utgard is a opensource implementation of DCOM(over JInterop) calls to OPC server, and because it work not in Windows security context, it can't use windows authentication to make DCOM calls. Therefore you should provide windows user credentials explicitly. Also by my experience implementation of DCOM by Utgard(JInterop) does not conforms all standards, and should be used carefully with production OPC servers.